# How to send all members a message in on_ready event discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When my bot starts up, I want it to send a message to all the members in each server, for example I want it to say `Hello`.

Any ideas?

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    sentmessage.toallmember.allserver("Hello")
    print("[+] Bot is ready")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this maliciously.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for m in bot.get_all_members():
        try: # this can fail if a user has DMs disabled
            await m.send("Something here")
        except:
            pass
    print("[+] Bot is ready")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Client.get_all_members()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_all_members)
- [`Member.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.send)

Comment: Did you make sure to put `await` before `m.send(..`?

Comment: Please could you edit your question with the new code that you have?

Comment: If it helped you, don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/someone-answers) as it might help someone else that's looking for the solution. Happy coding :^)